# Installing Driver for ATI Radeon HD 4000 Series

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

I am dual booting **Ubuntu 15.10** (**64-bit** / **Kernel 4.2.0-35-generic**) with OSX on my iMac (mid-2010). I managed to install, and am able to use, Ubuntu with the nomodeset workaround, but the monitor can't wake out of sleep and I can't play games without a proper graphics driver.

My question is: How do I install the most up-to-date graphics driver available for my **ATI Radeon HD 4670**? I realize it will almost certainly be third party, and that's fine.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit: I should add that I can't even adjust my brightness, which is my main concern as it makes my computer run really hot and also requires sunglasses.

**Edit: The currently installed driver is Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe and no drivers are available in the additional drivers option.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the open source software form additional driver option.
15.10 has some issues with fglrx driver as it has been stated in the release notes.

Comment: The fglrx driver only works for the 5000 series and later. Its legacy version is not compatible with my kernel version, nor is the official legacy driver from the AMD website.